# how to assign a "const void*" to a "const uint64_t*" in cuda c?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I want to assign "const void*" to a "const uint64_t*" in cuda c.

I have done like this,

```
void func(const void *buffer)
{
  const uint64_t *words = buffer;
}
```

but i'm getting an error like this,

> error: a value of type "const void *" cannot be used to initialize an
>   entity of type "const uint64_t *"

can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As @sharptooth indicated, this fixed it for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void func(const void *buffer)
{
  const uint64_t *words = (const uint64_t *) buffer;
}

int main(){

  void *my_buf=0;
  func(my_buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2214792 Depending on how many different systems this code will run on, and what the exact use case, it may be better to use uintptr_t.